# How can I align inputs and button styled link in bootstrap v4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a form with the grid system

I have a link (styled as a button) in a row, and I want it aligned with the inputs

I tried every combination of align-button and align-items-button but no success

Here the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77xmq6z0/8/)

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Test</a>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
</div>
```

and here how I'd like it[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap4 you should use **[bootstrap flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)** for this...

Add `d-flex align-items-end` class to the last column to align the `button` with `input`

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/hm83jqwc/)**

Comment: this works for me and uses only bootstrap utilities. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.btn-secondary {
  background: #666;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
    <label class='block' >&nbsp;</label>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary inline">Test</a>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Bootstrap 4, so your answer is for the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="testBtn">&nbsp;</label>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary form-control" id="testBtn">Test</a>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
</div>
</div>
```

Try this, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

in your last div (where you have the button) add as first child:

```
<label style="display: block">&nbsp;</label>
```

and I'd also suggest removing btn-sm class